# How to stop swagger auto generating GUID parameter passed to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a Reserve Input class which is being passed as a parameter to controller method. It all works fine but on the swagger page under parameters section, the GUID is auto filled. I want it to be empty and let user to pass the item id he wants to reserve.

[image]

```
    public class ReserveInput
    {
        [Required]
        public Guid ItemId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Address { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public DateTime ReserveDate { get; set; }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("ReserveItem")]
    public IActionResult ReserveItem([FromBody] ReserveItemInput input)
    {
       //Find item by GUI
       //Reserve an item
    }
```

Comment: Swagger just generates examples. when they connect to the API, there wont be a value pre-populated. The same way Address says "string"

Comment: @IAmGroot swagger does generate a value as shown in the screen shot.

Comment: Yes. I think you misunderstood me. What I am saying is that it is just an example, like how address says "string". What problems is this actually causing? The swagger page is documentation of the API. The API itself doesnt have a default, and they will need to send an ItemId when connecting over REST.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [DefaultValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.defaultvalueattribute?view=net-7.0) attribute.

Example:

```
[DefaultValue("")]
[Required]
public Guid ItemId { get; set; }
```

**Note**

Applies to versions `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore --version 3.0.0` and above.